I'm trying to retrieve timestamps from a Facebook group link using Selenium, but I'm encountering an issue where my code returns nothing
Here's the relevant code I'm using:
# Attempt to extract the timestamp
timestamp_elements = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("div.__fb-light-mode.xnkg4db.x3sdr18.x13ywhbb.xu98ijt span")')


In this line, I’m using execute_script to run a JavaScript query that selects span elements within a div that has a specific class structure. However, I suspect that this might not be selecting the correct elements.
Next, I'm trying to loop through the retrieved elements:
for timestamp_element in timestamp_elements:
    timestamp = timestamp_element.text
    # Get current date and time
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    timestamp_info.append((timestamp, f"Current time: {now}"))


In this section, I aim to extract the text from each timestamp element and pair it with the current date and time. However, it seems like timestamp_elements is empty, which is why nothing gets appended to timestamp_info.
Can anyone help me understand why this might not be working? Are there any adjustments I should make to successfully retrieve the timestamps?
